# pthread_create : passing an argument as the last argument

Tags: c++11, pthreads

I have the following functions :

```
void Servlet(SSL* ssl)  /* Serve the connection -- threadable */
{   char buf[1024];
char reply[1024];
int sd, bytes;
const char* HTMLecho="<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>\n\n";

if ( SSL_accept(ssl) == FAIL )          /* do SSL-protocol accept */
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
else
{

    ShowCerts(ssl);                             /* get any certificates */
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));    /* get request */
    if ( bytes > 0 )
    {
        buf[bytes] = 0;
        printf("Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        sprintf(reply, HTMLecho, buf);          /* construct reply */
        SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply));   /* send reply */
    }
    else
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);           /* get socket    connection */
    SSL_free(ssl);                                  /* release SSL state */
    close(sd);                                      /* close connection */
    }
```

and in main part program:

```
 pthread_create(&threadA[noThread], NULL, Servlet,(SSL*)(ssl));
```

But after compile, I see error for argument 3 pthread_create! how to fix it?

Comment: *"I see error for argument 3 pthread_create! how to fix it"*. First step: Read the error message.

Comment: error message"invalid conversation from void (*)(ssl*) to void* (*)(void*) [-fpermisive]"

Comment: You should put relevant information like that into the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the declaration of `pthread_create`, you'll find that the third argument (the call back) is of type `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`. Such function pointer can point to a function of type `void*(void*)` i.e. a function that returns a `void*` and takes an argument of type `void*`.

Your function `Servlet` takes an argument of type `SSL*` rather than `void*` and returns `void` rather than `void*`. Therefore your function cannot be convertible of that other function pointer type and as such your call to `pthread_create` is ill-formed.

Solution: Use a function with the correct signature. Use `void*` as the argument, and return a `void*`.

Another approach: Use `std::thread` from the C++ standard library instead of pthreads.

Comment: tnx for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by myself:

for call pthread_create:

```
pthread_create(&threadA[noThread], NULL, Servlet,(void*) ssl);
```

and in body of start routine:

```
void * Servlet(void *param) 
{
  SSL *ssl = (SSL *)param;
  //..
}
```